# How to initialize an empty struct type in C

Tags: c

I have the following line in the header :

```
typedef struct x;
```

In the main code I want to define the structure for example:

```
typedef struct x
{
   int a;
   int b;
}
```

When i compile the code it  gives me the error: redefinition of struct x
o how can i do it without changing the header?

Comment: Please provide the actual code (i.e. [mre]) and the actual error messages provided.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the type-alias a name:

```
// structure name
//             v
typedef struct x x;
//               ^
// type-alias name
```

And you can define that name only once (i.e. only *one* `typedef`), so drop the type-aliasing when defining the structure:

```
struct x
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

Comment: i can't define the struct with something in it at the beggining

Comment: @AndriNic `typedef struct x x;` will do a *forward **declaration*** of `struct x`, but it won't define the structure. Doing like this is very common for  [opaque data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type) in C.